# "TypeError" for a simple program causing failure to compile, "Type address is not implicitly convertible to expected type address payable."

Tags: solidity, contract-debugging

This is my first contract (working from Lynda course). Even when I use the supplied code I still age this error for the following code with I try to compile:

TypeError: Type address is not implicitly convertible to expected type address payable.
    receiver = _receiver;
               ^-------^

Compilation failed. See above.

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.16;

contract ApprovalContract {

  address public sender;
  address payable public receiver;
  address constant public approver = 0xd268143B6FBD9BC6533F778052710C962eaAa68C;

  function ApprovalContracts() public {
    // tbd
  }

  function deposit(address _receiver) external payable {
    require(msg.value > 0);
    sender = msg.sender;
    receiver = _receiver;
  }

    function viewApprover() external pure returns(address) {
    return(approver);
  }

   function approve() external {
    require(msg.sender == approver);
    receiver.transfer(address(this).balance);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

**The Error:**

`TypeError: Type address is not implicitly convertible to expected type address payable. receiver = _receiver; ^-------^`

The compiler reports such errors whenever you assign a variable of type `address` to a variable of type `address payable`

**In Solidity:**

The address type comes in two flavors, which are largely identical:

- **address**: Holds a 20-byte value (size of an Ethereum address).
- **address payable**: Same as an address, but with the additional members transfer and send.

`The idea behind this distinction is that address payable is an address you can send Ether to, while a plain address cannot be sent Ether`

[Address Data Type in Soldity](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.6.4/types.html#address)

In your code:

```
address payable public receiver;
receiver = _receiver;
```

`inside deposit function, here _receiver is of type address and not address payable`

In order to fix this error, change deposit functions signature to:

```
function deposit(address payable _receiver) external payable {
    // Logic remains the same
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add **payable** to this line ***receiver.transfer(address(this).balance);***

make sure you are add **brackets** to the receiver

Dont repeat a function name same as contract name, use **constructor** instead

Here the **code** should be according to **solidity version 0.8.9**

```
 pragma solidity ^0.8.9;

 contract ApprovalContract {

 address public sender;
 address payable public receiver;
 address constant public approver = ; //address

 constructor() {
 // tbd
 }

 function deposit(address _receiver) external payable {
 require(msg.value > 0);
 sender = msg.sender;
 receiver = _receiver;
 }

 function viewApprover() external pure returns(address) {
 return(approver);
 }

 function approve() external {
 require(msg.sender == approver);
 payable(receiver).transfer(address(this).balance);
 }
}
```